# Etale covers of $\mathbb{G}_{m,k}$ in char 0

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory, ramification, etale-cohomology

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic 0. It seems it is well known that étale covers of $\mathbb{G}_{m,k}=\operatorname{Spec}(k[T^{\pm 1}])$ are in bijection with étale covers of $\operatorname{Spec}(k(\!(T)\!))$.

I'd like to understand this by myself, as much as I can. This means I'm here mainly for hints.

What is the good "language" to study étale covers of $\mathbb{G}_m$? I know that, in characteristic 0, connected étale covers of $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ are trivial, i.e. they are the same as connected étale covers of $k$, i.e. they corresponds to finite (separable, but everything is separble in char 0) extensions of $k$.

This is proved, for instance in *Galois Theory for Schemes* by H.W. Lenstra (6.23) via ramification theory of valuations, with references to some chapters of *Intro. to theory of algebraic functions in one variable* by Chevalley.

I don't know much of valuation theory and I'm wondering if this "language" may help me to classify étale covers of $\mathbb{G}_m$. I believe it would help me indeed, but maybe there are some other kind of arguments that would solve my problem.

(I apologize for the tag "étale cohomology", maybe it's an overkill, but it was the only tag with the word "étale")

Comment: It would probably help if you start by studying the finite degree topological covers of $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$. Next, it would also help if you use the Riemann-Hurwitz to compute the genus of a finite morphism $X\to \mathbb{P}^1$ with at most two branch points. Finally, maybe the book of Szamuely on Galois theory and fundamental groups would be good to look at.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Ariyan. Finite topological covers of $\mathbb{C}^\times$ "are" finite $\widehat{\pi_1(\mathbb{C}^\times)}=\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$-sets (with continuous action), and I know how to use Riemann-Hurwitz formula (for Riemann surfaces) to compute the genus of $X$. But 1) I don't see how I can use R-H to classify covers 2) how to translate this for any field $k$ of characteristic 0.

Comment: Finite topological covers $X$ of $\mathbb{C}^\times$  with $X$ connected are isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^\times$, and the map from $X$ to $\mathbb{C}^\times$ is $z\mapsto z^d$ with $d$ the degree of the covering. Can you prove this?

For $k$ an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero: let $X\to \mathbb{G}_{m,k}$ be a finite etale morphism with $X$ connected. Then, choose a subfield $k_0\subset k$, an embedding $k_0\to \mathbb{C}$ and a model $\mathcal{X}\to \mathbb{G}_{m,k_0}$ for $X\to \mathbb{G}_{m,k}$ over $k_0$. (Can you prove why this is always possible?)

Comment: Now, once you have this, consider the base-change $\mathcal{X}_{\mathbb{C}}\to \mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}}$ along the embedding $k_0\to \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Now you are over the field of complex numbers. Analytify and apply the topological fact mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: If $k$ is an arbitrary field of char zero, you have to account for the finite field extensions $L/k$ as well, as these also give finite etale covers $\mathbb{G}_{m,L}\to \mathbb{G}_{m,k}$. But I assume here that you are only interested in the geometric fundamental group. No?

Comment: What do you mean by a ''model''?

Comment: A model for $X$ over $k_0$ is a pair $(\mathcal{X},\phi)$   with $\mathcal{X}\to Spec$  $k_0$ a curve over $k_0$ and $\phi:\mathcal{X}_k\to X$ an isomorphism. (We usually omit $\phi$ from the notation.) Concretely: a model for a variety $X/k$ over a subfield $k_0$ is the choice of equations and glueing data defining $X$ which all have "coefficients" in $k_0$.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to argue along the following lines.

---

If you have read through the notes of Lenstra which you cited, then it should be clear that the question is the following:

> Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$, and write $K$ for $k(t)$.
>
> There is a bijection between:
>
> - finite extensions $L/K$ which are unramified at all places of $K$, except for the infinite place $v_\infty$ and the place $v_0$ at $t = 0$;
> - finite extensions of $k((t))$.

As a first remark, if $L/K$ is unramified outside $v_0$ and $v_\infty$, then there can be only one place of $L$ above $v_0$ (same for $v_\infty$). This follows from the Riemann-Hurwitz formula.

Therefore in one direction we have a well-defined map: taking $E = L \otimes_K k((t))$ gives us the completion of $L$ at the unique place above $v_0$, and this is a finite extension of $k((t))$.

---

It remains to see that this map is a bijection.

There is, I believe, middle steps:

> (1) Every finite extension of $k((t))$ is of the form $k'((t^{1/n}))$, where $k'/k$ is a finite extension and $n$ is a positive integer.

And on the other side:

> (2) Every finite extension $L/K$ which is unramified outside $v_0$ and $v_\infty$ is of the form $k'(t^{1/n})$, where $k'/k$ is a finite extension and $n$ is a positive integer.

---

Both (1) and (2) are not so obvious, though. Perhaps it's worth pointing out that they are all specially for function fields: the number field counterparts are far from being true.